# What's the fourier transform of $\cos(bt)u(t)$?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have been trying to find the Fourier Transform of $\cos(bt).u(t)$

I applied the definition
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(bt).u(t).e^{-jwt} dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(bt).e^{-jwt} dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{jbt} + e^{-jbt}}{2} .e^{-jwt} dt$$
Which simplifies to $$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{j(b-w)t} + e^{-j(b+w)t}dt$$

But now I'll need to compute $e^\infty$ which isn't computable

How to handle this case?

Comment: It looks like $u(t)=1_{[0,\infty]}$. But $\cos(bt)u(t)\notin L^1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$, so the fourier-transform isn't defined. Or, are you looking for the fourier-transform in the sense of distribution?

Comment: It is a question in my university assignment, I get that it is undefined so that's why I'm asking my question

Comment: Also wolfram alpha seems to be able to find the fourier transform of the function